# "dd/MM/yyyy" format not validating YEAR in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, customvalidator

I tried to validate the date using custom validation in spring boot. But the only `yyyy` is not validating the year although `dd` and `MM` is working fine.

For Example,

if in RequestBody I passed the date format as

`02/1k/2022`, is validated properly and also `k2/12/2022` is validated properly but
when I passed a date like `02/12/2k22` is not validated.

I couldn't figure out it.

SpringBoot version: **2.3.0.RELEASE**

**Dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Code:**

```
public class IsValidDateFormatValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IsValidDateFormat, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(IsValidDateFormat arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String arg0, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {

        if (arg0 != null) {
            if (arg0.trim().length() > 10) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!arg0.isEmpty()) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                sdf.setLenient(false);
                try {
                    sdf.parse(arg0);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {IsValidDateFormatValidator.class})
@Documented
public @interface IsValidDateFormat {

    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

**Model:**

```
@NotEmpty(message = "dob {emptyDateValidationMsg}")
@IsValidDateFormat(message = "dob {dateFormatValidationMsg}")
@JsonProperty("dob")
private String dob;
```

Please suggest what mistake I made...

The same code was validating the year properly if I passed dateformat **yyyy-MM-dd** instead of **dd/MM/yyyy**

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some flaws if you use SimpleDateFormat.parse, that "*The method may not use the entire text of the given string*". You can find that in javadoc [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-)

I suggest you can use DateTimeFormatter & LocalDate.parse instead.

```
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        LocalDate.parse(arg0, formatter);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
```